# Making a user form appear as if it is in an Excel worksheet rather than seperate

Tags: excel, vba, activex, userform

I want my user form to appear as if it is actually part of an Excel worksheet rather than a separate window from the Excel workbook.  I am unable to use the ActiveX Controls which would actually be located in the worksheet because I need to designate a RawSource for my ComboBoxes which isn't an option under the ActiveX version.  Is there a way that I can make my userform appear as if it is in the worksheet like it would if I was using the ActiveX Controls?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a userform appear "within" the sheet.

I don't know your idea behind your request. If you want to be able to use the form and the sheet in parallel, you could show your form Non-Modal (`userform1.show False`)

However, you could use ActiveX controls. You can access those controls from VBA and set the rowSource (the property is named `ListFillRange`) to a Range, or you can set the items individually (however you cannot mix this).

Set to a Range:

```
Dim ctrl As OLEObject
Set ctrl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("ComboBox1")
ctrl.ListFillRange = "A2:A10"
```

Set to a individual list of items:

```
with ctrl
    .ListFillRange = ""    ' Make sure that ListFillRange  is empty
    With .object           ' "Object" is the real ComboBox object
        .clear
        .AddItem "Cheese"
        .AddItem "Tomato"
        .AddItem "Onion"
        .AddItem "Ham"
        .AddItem "Olives"
        
        .Value = "Onion"
    End With
End With
```

If you prefer, you can also write

```
Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "A2:A10"
```

or

```
Sheet1.ComboBox1.Clear
Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Hello"
```

This assumes that the *codeName* of the sheet is `Sheet1` - the codeName is visible in the VBA Project View and may differ from the sheet name.